# Have phpmyadmin and apache, but need to log in to database (Linux Mint)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I am new to linux but learning it pretty well.   I have apache working on localhost, I installed mysql through this package: mysql-server 8.0.19-obuntu5

But I need to create a user that works with phpmymadmin and mysql and has access to all the databases.  I'm getting these error with root (would post photo but the photos are causing post problems):

> Cannot log into mysql server then
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

See my config here, without the dollar sign char for vars and colins:

```
dbuser 'root'
dbpass 'Edited Out For This Post'
basepath ''
dbname 'phpmyadmin'
dbserver 'localhost'
dbport '3306'
dbtype 'mysql'
```

What should I do to get me logged into all my dbs.  Willing to make new user.

Comment: Welcome to Linux world!

Answer (score 0):

Many versions of phpmyadmin disallows root login. Hence, run the following to login as root (in console)

```
sudo mysql -p -u root
```

then create a new user (say pmauser) with

```
CREATE USER 'pmauser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password_here';
```

then grant this user the permission

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pmauser'@'localhost';
```

Now try login phpmyadmin by pmauser